# Obj-c, whats the least lines of code to get the current date without hour, minutes, seconds and millseconds?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ios, nsdate

I want to produce a date without hours, minutes, seconds or milliseconds.

I've tried `[NSDate date]` but that adds them.

Hows can I do this ?

Comment: You've solutions for both Mac OS X and iOS below, but in future you might want to specify which of the two you're after via the relevant tag. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

[dateFormatter release];
```

Adjust the date style to suit.

Or, as suggested, use `setDateFormat`; something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: Think you can use setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd" on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Something like...

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSDate date]
    descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d" timeZone:nil
    locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]]);
```

...should do the trick on Mac OS X.